# Циклическая карта мира. Unity3d

Tags: unity3d

Unity3d
Есть картинка карты мира и orthographic camera, которую можно двигать по карте, увеличить/ уменьшать. Нужно сделать так , чтобы при достижении края карты, показывалась картинка карты с другого края. Чтобы получилась бесшовная карта, которую можно бесконечно двигать вправо/влево, как это сделано в google maps. Есть у кого-нибудь идеи как это можно реализовать?

Comment: В DirectX SDK есть такой пример. Но C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть 2 способа:

1. Изменять оффсет текстуры плейна и при этом сам плейн размещать всегда на уровне игрока/камеры.
2. Создать 2 картинки и просто передвигать одну из них вперед когда камера направлена на вторую.